# How use Spring OAuth2 authentication for user registration/sign-in for a mobile backend only?

Tags: java, spring, react-native

I am developing a mobile phone app, and I am currently writing the backend for it with the Spring Framework in Java. I would like to support user sign-in with Google, Facebook, etc. via OAuth2.

Spring supports OAuth2, and I got it to work with the Spring web app itself. However, the Spring app is going to be strictly a REST API that deals with user creation, sign in, and data. Therefore, I have run into the issue of figuring out what to do. I want this API to confirm OAuth2 logins and correlate that to registration/sign-in, accessing data, etc.

I want the user to be able to sign-in through Google, Facebook, Apple, etc. on my mobile app frontend, but where my Spring backend is able to "confirm" the OAuth2 authentication & sign-in after doing so. Then I can use the unique identifier tied to that to create an account for them in my own database.

What would be an ideal approach for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.